# How to add a class to parent if child has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I have this html structure:

```
<section>
      <div class="v-middle">
        <div class="row">
          <h5 class="heading">Heading goes here</h5>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

And I need to add the class "newClass" to the parent **Section** tag when the **h5** has **.heading** class.

I tried the following but it didn't work and I don't know why:

```
 $('.heading').parent('section').addClass('newClass');
```

**DEMO**

https://fiddle.jshell.net/4smhxoL6/1/

Comment: You forgot to add jquery to fiddle

Comment: heading's parent is not a section, it is a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parent` looks at the immediate parent, which isn't a `section`, but a `div`. You want `closest`:

```
$('.heading').closest('section').addClass('newClass');
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/4smhxoL6/2/

Answer (score 1):

you could use [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjy0uPrjt7UAhVKQY8KHb-WClcQFgi8ATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ) instead of `parent()` .parent matching immediate parent. `closest` matching the parent first  `section` detect

```js
 $('.heading').closest('section').addClass('newClass');
```

```css
section {
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.newClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
      <div class="v-middle">
        <div class="row">
          <h5 class="heading">Heading goes here</h5>
         </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change parent to parents.

```
$('.heading').parents('section').addClass('newClass');
```

or

You can use

```
$('.heading').closest('section').addClass('newClass');
```

working fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/1y3ejtjz/

Answer (score 1):

All of the posted answers are forgetting 1 thing:

> And I need to add the class "newClass" to the parent Section tag **when**
>   **the h5 has .heading class**.

`newClass` should only be applied when the `<h5>` element has `heading` class.

This code should do the trick.

```
var heading = $('.heading');

if (heading.length && heading.is('h5')) {
    heading.closest('section').addClass('newClass');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4yo72hhd/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `parent` method,try `parentsUntil` method.For details,see [jQuery Traversing - Ancestors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_ancestors.asp)

```
$('.heading').parentsUntil('section').addClass('newClass');
```

**Demo**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    section {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .newClass {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <div class="v-middle">
      <div class="row">
        <h5 class="heading">Heading goes here</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.heading').parentsUntil('section').addClass('newClass');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for specific h5 with .heading class. Because if this heading class available in other element this will protect you.

```
$('h5.heading').closest('section').addClass('newClass')
```